# Don't understand some part of query

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I'm trying to analyze this query. 
But I just don't understand ) CNT, ) SUMT, ) DT_G.

Why do they put those and what do they mean by? Can anyone explain?

```
 (
     SELECT 
                                 NVL(DT_G.COMM_DT, 'TOTAL') COMM_DT
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.MOVIE_500K), 0) AS MOVIE_500K
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.MOVIE_1M), 0) AS MOVIE_1M
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.MOVIE), 0) AS MOVIE
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.EXAM), 0) AS EXAM
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.DOC), 0) AS DOC 
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.IMG), 0) AS IMG
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.WEB), 0) AS WEB
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.INTERRAC), 0) AS INTERRAC
                       FROM 
                                (
                                 SELECT
                                              COMM_DT
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP10' THEN SUMT.SUM_500K END MOVIE_500K
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP10' THEN SUMT.SUM_1M END AS MOVIE_1M
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP10' THEN SUMT.SUM_500K+SUMT.SUM_1M END AS MOVIE
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP11' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS EXAM
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP12' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS DOC
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP13' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS IMG
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP14' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS WEB
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP01' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS INTERRAC
                                  FROM (

SELECT RSC_TP_DSCD, SUM(STDY_CNT) AS SUM_STD_CNT, SUM(MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N1M) AS SUM_1M, SUM(MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N500K) AS SUM_500K, COMM_DT
    FROM (
            SELECT RSC_SNO, STDY_CNT, MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N1M, MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N500K, COMM_DT
               FROM LRMS.V_EBSM_PKG_RSC_COMM_CNT
            WHERE PKG_SNO = 0  AND RSC_SNO != 0
            AND COMM_DT BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20130501', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20130530', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD')
            ) CNT
         LEFT OUTER JOIN LRMS.V_LRRM_RSC RSC ON CNT.RSC_SNO = RSC.RSC_SNO
    GROUP BY RSC_TP_DSCD, COMM_DT
     ) SUMT
   ) DT_G
 GROUP BY ROLLUP(DT_G.COMM_DT)
) RSC ON DAY.DAY = RSC.COMM_DT
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this query is incomplete, as there are many unbalanced parenthesis.  Could you verify if this is the correct query?

Comment: I just added the whole query. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This select has multiple embedded subqueries in it, that basically treats every select surrounded by a parenthesis as a view (in other words, the data gets presented as a table, even though its not exactly a table).

The way you evaluate this is similar to how function calls are made in imperative programming languages (like C, or Java).  You first evaluate the inner most query.

Lets look at them.

### First: CNT

```
(
SELECT RSC_SNO, STDY_CNT, MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N1M, MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N500K, COMM_DT
FROM LRMS.V_EBSM_PKG_RSC_COMM_CNT
WHERE PKG_SNO = 0  AND RSC_SNO != 0
    AND COMM_DT BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20130501', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20130530', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD')
    ) CNT
```

This is the first subquery to be evaluated.  The subquery will be treated from now on as a view (again, a representation of the select query data result as a table), called CNT.  This CNT will have the columns:

```
RSC_SNO, STDY_CNT, MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N1M, MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N500K, COMM_DT
```

So from now on, you could make make reference to CNT.RSC_SNO, which refers to the RSC_SNO column from that previoius select.

Remember that, from now on CNT is going to represent that first query.

### Second: SUMT

```
    (
SELECT RSC_TP_DSCD, SUM(STDY_CNT) AS SUM_STD_CNT, SUM(MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N1M) AS SUM_1M, SUM(MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N500K) AS SUM_500K, COMM_DT
FROM CNT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LRMS.V_LRRM_RSC RSC ON CNT.RSC_SNO = RSC.RSC_SNO
GROUP BY RSC_TP_DSCD, COMM_DT
    ) SUMT
```

See where I wrote 'FROM CNT'?  That entails the previous select is being handled as if it where a table, so you are doing a select based on that previous result set
(In reality, when writing the query, you should include the whole '(...) CNT' but omitted it for simplicity)

Keep applying this same logic through each subquery, and that's what your query is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe " CNT,  SUMT,  DT_G" are aliases for the inline views.